# Google Play: Is it possible to move users between subscriptions?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

QUESTION:
Is it possible to move users between subscriptions on Google Play?

SITUATION:
We have to increase the price for one country, but we want to leave the current users with the old price and only show the new subscription in-app.

Result: old users can still use their old price, but the subscription won't be possible to buy because it's not displayed. New users will only see the new subscription in-app.

BETTER CONTEXT:
We need to create a new price for Germany, but still keeping the old users with the current price.
For that, that solution we've found is to create a new product_id for the subscription and switch it in-app and keep the old subscription live, but not being displayed anywhere.
This way, we can keep the old users with the previous price and for new users, they will see the new price.

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference is someone needs, I've contacted Google Support and this was their answer:

*Thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support.

I checked into it and the Play Console doesn’t currently support the requested option.
Luckily, we place a high value on developer feedback, and I’ll be sure to pass along your specific feedback to our product team. We’re continually adding new features and functionality, so please stay tuned.*